# how to get request header and response header by webkitGTK

Tags: webkit, httpresponse

I want to get the request header before the webkitGTK begin to send request and load the page. Then I want to get the response headers. However, I don't find such API in webkitGTK.

Answer (score 1):

In Webkit1 the signal you want is [WebKitWebView::resource-request-starting](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/unstable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-resource-request-starting): The `request` argument contains a WebKitNetworkRequest which has a SoupMessage which will allow you to modify the request headers. The same signal has `resource` argument which has a  [response-received](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/unstable/WebKitWebResource.html#WebKitWebResource-response-received) which in turn will contain a WebKitNetworkResponse. The SoupMessage of that response will have the response headers you want.

In Webkit2GTK the [WebKitWebView::resource-load-started](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/unstable/WebKitWebView.html#WebKitWebView-resource-load-started) should be useful for at least monitoring: `request` and `resource` arguments work almost like the WebKit1 versions. The bit that I'm not 100% sure about is whether you can modify the request headers here -- or if you have to implement a WebExtension and use the [WebKitWebPage::send-request](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/unstable/WebKitWebPage.html#WebKitWebPage-send-request) signal.